# Как показать Preloader до загрузки iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('*[data-target=".humanpower"]').click(function(){
        if(!$('#humanpower').length) {
                $('#humanpower_bl').html('<iframe id="humanpower" src="http://....."></iframe>');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно отследить событие onload в котором удалить preloader. Можно еще добавит картинку через background.

```js
document.querySelector('iframe').onload = iframeOnload

function iframeOnload () {
 document.querySelector('.preloader').remove()
}
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/A-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg) center center no-repeat;
}

.preloader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <iframe src="..."></iframe>
  <div class="preloader" id="preloader">
    <p>Загрузка...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```